# Woocommerce | Wordpress - WC_Cart::set_quantity -

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing an e-commerce website.
I'm trying to set a cart item quantity using an ajax request.

I got this

```
if (isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['new_quantity'])) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($_POST['product_id'], $_POST['new_quantity']);
}
```

I also tried with

```
WC()->....
```

but it doesn't work and throws this error

> Call to a member function needs_shipping() on null in 
>        **C:\xampp\htdocs\findandcandy\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-cart.php** on line **1514**

What can be causing this to happen?

If you need me to show some more code please tell me.
Thanks

Comment: And the line 1514 of `class-wc-cart.php` is the one with `$woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($_POST['product_id'], $_POST['new_quantity']);`?

Comment: @Technoh No, class-wc-cart.php is a core file from woocommerce. im calling that piece of code from another file. I found the needs_shipping() function in the class-wc-cart.php file, wich is a function from WC_Product class. by the error it throws i guess it must be null when i'm calling set_quantity function. Why iis it null i dont know.

Comment: I think you're making a new product through this if the $_POST['product_id'] is not the $cart_item_key which is the id of the cart item.

Comment: I agree with TeeDeJee

Answer (score 0):

I added `if(is_object($_product))` at line 1514 and it resolved my issue.